# Angular5 :polyfills.ts & \main.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli, package.json

This is my Angular5 project structure.

[image]

Both `tsconfig.app.json` and `package.json` contain this section

```
 "include": [
      "/src/main.ts",
      "/src/polyfills.ts"
    ]
```

But no matter what I try I still get this error:

```
    \polyfills.ts & \main.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. 
Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
```

[image]
Anyone has idea what's missing here?

```
  tsconfig.json
        {
          "compileOnSave": false,
          "compilerOptions": {
            "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
            "sourceMap": true,
            "declaration": false,
            "moduleResolution": "node",
            "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
            "experimentalDecorators": true,
            "target": "es5",
            "typeRoots": [
              "node_modules/@types"
            ],
            "lib": [
              "es2017",
              "dom"
            ]
          }
        }
src/tsconfig.app.json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "include": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Kindly provide full context if src\tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.json files

Comment: Post updated....

Comment: Seems ok for me.. What is typescript version? And try  ./main.ts path. One more possibility - try 'files' instead of 'include'

Comment: And try to update angular cli

Comment: I am getting same error but if I run the local environment with --aot flag then this issue seems to get resolved somehow.

I would still like to get some explanation for this

Answer (score 32):

Found the solution.  The problem is because I was in a symbolic link directory  ($HOME/dev -> d:\dev\ )
Move to the original directory (d:\dev) and run your commands and it works.

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9909

Comment: Same issue on Windows 10 having a directory junction (mklink /j)!

Comment: Editing angular.json to add following attribute under the node "projects/{yourprojectname}/architect/build/options" should help:
"preserveSymlinks": true

Comment: Shut the front door

Comment: Same issue here! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 11):

Editing **angular.json** to add following attribute under the node `projects/project/architect/build/options` should help make `"preserveSymlinks": true` work.

```
{
  ...  
  "projects": {
    "<your_project_name>": {
      ...  
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...  
          "options": {
            ...
            "preserveSymlinks": true
          }
          ...
         }
       }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: As hours of my (previously working Angular) not building, this has made the problem go away...  but what the heck does this actually do ?   I hadn't moved the source code to a different folder or anything....

Comment: This is the correct answer, for me in Angular 12.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this today while trying to use Git Bash on Windows 10 to build an Angular 9 app.

Turned out that *the file paths were too long/nested* for Git Bash to handle! That, or Git Bash was using symbolic links instead in some places.

Ran the `ng build` from Cmd / PowerShell instead, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue with my `src/polyfills.ts` file only, as it was missing from the `"files"` array in `tsconfig.app.json`.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this problem for a while, and I solved it by just changing the location of my project. I put it in the disk other than that of the system (example: d :, e: ...)

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this in an Angular 16 project, on Windows using Git Bash.

The issue turned out to be a path casing issue: The "real" path was /c/src/Web/TheProject, but cd:ing to the same path with different casing, such as /c/src/web/TheProject (lower case W on the web folder) is possible in Git Bash, and gives these issues when doing `npm run build` from this location.

The solution is to ensure the Git Bash path name casing for the current working directory matches Windows path name casing. In our case, a simple `cd /c/src/Web/TheProject` made the issue go away.

Just mentioning this because it is a trivial mistake to make, and the other suggested solutions weren't giving us any helpful clues as we had a short path without symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue happening on Windows 10, and incorrect casing in my filepath was the issue. Short of the long is I had done a cd into D:\source\ when the directory is actually D:\Source\ (with a capital S). Changing the working directory to D:\Source fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

It's possibly because you're using an absolute path.

Try changing from:

```
"/src/main.ts",
```

to

```
"src/main.ts",
```

(Or possibly just `"main.ts"`)