# How can i solve "Error: \src\main.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation."

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, webpack

I tried all the possible solution on StackOverFlow and i have also uninstalled node and angular both. 3 Times in 3 days.
I have no idea why it happens.
This happens on "ng-serve"

```
C:\...\my-app>ng serve
Your global Angular CLI version (10.2.0) is greater than your local
version (10.1.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2.78 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 1.61 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 1.56 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 342 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-10-29T15:32:18.382Z - Hash: 73a81c6903f44c830485 - Time: 5411ms

ERROR in C:\...\my-app/src/main.ts
Module build failed (from C:\...\my-app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: C:\...\my-app\src\main.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (C:\...\my-app\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:949:23)
    at C:\...\my-app\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:43:31
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

ERROR in C:\...\my-app/src/polyfills.ts
Module build failed (from C:\...\my-app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: C:\...\my-app\src\polyfills.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (C:\...\my-app\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:949:23)
    at C:\...\my-app\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:43:31
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Use the windows command prompt with angular-cli instead of the bash shell and you should be good to go.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular5 :polyfills.ts & \main.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49091956/angular5-polyfills-ts-main-ts-is-missing-from-the-typescript-compilation)

Comment: Randy Casburn iam using CMD now, what do you mean?

Comment: there is a known, intermittent issue with the git bash shell and symlinks. Apparently that is not your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. Upgrade to angular 10.2.0 as is your angular CLI
2. Update all your dependencies `npm oudated` and then `npm update` if
   required.
3. Delete your dist folder and your node_modules files and use `npm install` and then `ng  serve`

Comment: How can i update angular of the project? Of the node_modules i mean

Comment: Change it in package.json

Comment: the one in  node_modules\@angular\cli\package.json?

Comment: No!? The one in the root of your projet with all your dependencies...

Comment: Hi i'have been trying for 2 weeks and nothing works. I also tried to create another project but the error remains... What can i do?

Comment: Try to upgrade your angular cli and then restart a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance using a symlinked location for the source code and compiling from the link location?
If so you should add

```
"preserveSymlinks": true,
```

to your **angular.json** under *projects/[your project name]/architect/build/options*.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my app to Angular 11 and had same build errors. This issue fixed for me when I downgraded below package in package.json file.

From:

`"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.17",
}`

To:

`"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.2",
}`